# C# - Separar/cortar string por vírgulas (porém com valor monetário incluso na string)

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema ao ler um arquivo txt que tem suas colunas separadas por vírgula mas que também possui valores monetários que estão sendo cortados e não deveriam, pois eles estão entre aspas. Segue exemplo da linha:

```
Nome, Idade, Valor a receber, Valor pendente, descricao
Teste, 25, "1.234,30", "987,90", teste
```

depois de já ter lido o arquivo

```
string[] todasLinhas = File.ReadAllLines(arquivo, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

eu tento cortar por virgula

```
foreach (string linha in todasLinhas)
{
   string[] colunas = linha.Split(',');
}
```

o resultado fica desta forma:

```
Teste
25
"1234
30"
"987
90"
teste
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer com que o Split não corte quando o caracter estiver entre aspas? ou se existe alguma outra solução que vocês possam compartilhar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o seu caso do seu exeplo eu recomendo fazer `split` por vírgula com espaço:

```
string[] colunas = linha.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Se você preferir usar `Regex`, pode fazer split por vírgulas não seguidas de número ou letra(caso as palavras também tenham vírgula), mas será menos eficiente e para seu exemplo o resultado é igual:

```
string[] colunas = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@",[^\d\w]").Split(linha);
```

Se as colunas estiverem separadas somente por vírgula, você pode dar um `split` por vírgula e depois concatenar as posições que começam com aspas duplas:

```
var colunas = new List<string>();
var linhasSplit = linha.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < linhasSplit.Length; i++)
{
    if(linhasSplit[i][0] == '"')
        colunas.Add(linhasSplit[i] + linhasSplit[++i]);
    else
        colunas.Add(linhasSplit[i]);
}
```

Comment: Daniel Dutra, obrigado pela resposta, mas acontece das linhas não ter espaço depois da vírgula, então a primeira opção não servirá, apesar de ser uma boa solução. A segunda opção não deu certo. Será que é pelo mesmo motivo?

Comment: Sim, é pelo menos motivo. A segunda solução sem espaços só vai dar split em vírgula antes de caractere especial.

Comment: Inclui uma solução para o caso de não existirem espaços. A solução está grande e feia, mas funciona. Depois eu tento melhorá-la.