# Converter numero c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como converter R$3.852,00 e salvar no banco esses . e ,? Segue meu código.

```
 public ImportProcesso()
        {
            ImportProcesso processo = new ImportProcesso();
            processo.dataReqPgto = new System.DateTime();
            processo.datRecebOrigem = new System.DateTime();
            processo.datSEP = new System.DateTime();
            processo.dscComarca = "";
            processo.dscmunicipio = "";
            processo.endereco = "";
            processo.nmebairro = "";
            processo.nmeInteressado = "";
            processo.nmeVara ="";
            processo.numero = "";
            processo.numProcAnterior = "";
            processo.numProcJudicial = "";
            processo.numVara = 0;
            processo.vlrbruto = System.Decimal ;
```

Aceito sugestão caso tenha que complementar mais informações. essa estrutura está correta do método?

Comment: Creio eu que a unica forma é tornar esse campo string. decimal vai salvar o valor com os decimais, mas não com a separacao de milhar.

Comment: vc teria um exemplo de como seria convertendo o numero com a separação de milhar?

Comment: É irrelevante salvar o ponto do milhar e do milhão se quando você transformar ele em um tipo numeral ele vai perder esse simbolo. Se o problema é apenas para apresentação é melhor utilizar uma mascara monetária.

Comment: Boa solução do Gabriel...Segue alguns exemplos.  C#
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129549/c-separar-cortar-string-por-v%C3%ADrgulas-por%C3%A9m-com-valor-monet%C3%A1rio-incluso-na-st
e em Javascript 
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188190/formatar-moeda-com-separador-de-milhar

Comment: Qual banco de dados (SGBD) esta usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe `NumberFormatInfo` para especificar as informações que contem no valor numérico correspondente. Além disso, é importante que você teste o máximo de entradas possíveis para impedir que valores inconsistentes sejam armazenados ou que gere possíveis erros ou problemas futuros.

Criei a função `StrCurrencyToDecimal()` para converter o valor em dinheiro para o tipo `decimal`, veja:

```
decimal StrCurrencyToDecimal(string str)
{
    NumberFormatInfo infoCurrency = new NumberFormatInfo();
    infoCurrency.NegativeSign = "-";
    infoCurrency.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
    infoCurrency.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
    infoCurrency.CurrencySymbol = "R$";

    if (decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Currency, infoCurrency, out var result))     
        return result;      

    return -1;
}
```

A função retorna `-1` no caso de valores inválidos, é só para ilustração, no entanto, existe maneiras mais apropriadas para isto, você até pode usar códigos de erro. De uma lida [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21768/27190) que aborda este assunto.

Veja o código completo:

```
using System.Globalization;
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {                   
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("R$3.852,00"));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("R$0,00"));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("R$-3.852,00"));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal(""));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("R3.852,00"));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("$3.852,00"));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("3.852,00"));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("R$3ad.852,00"));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("R$3,852.00"));
        WriteLine("Valor: {0}", StrCurrencyToDecimal("assR$3,852.00"));
    }       

    static decimal StrCurrencyToDecimal(string str)
    {
        NumberFormatInfo infoCurrency = new NumberFormatInfo();
        infoCurrency.NegativeSign = "-";
        infoCurrency.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
        infoCurrency.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
        infoCurrency.CurrencySymbol = "R$";

        if (decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Currency, infoCurrency, out var result))     
            return result;      

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Valor: 3852.00
>   Valor: 0.00
>   Valor: -3852.00
>   Valor: -1
>   Valor: -1
>   Valor: -1
>   Valor: -1
>   Valor: -1
>   Valor: -1
>   Valor: -1

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gL2c0n).

Aprenda mais sobre a [classe NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use o seguinte método

```
    public static decimal Sem_Simbolo(string pValor_Reais)
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(pValor_Reais.Replace("R$", string.Empty));
    }
```

Ou converta direto, tanto faz.
Mas vai salvar como decimal, como o banco tá pedindo, ou seja, o valor salvo será 3852,00, sem o ponto.

Comment: no banco esta como Number(15,2), estou tentando converter esse campo  ImportProcesso processo = new ImportProcesso();
            processo.dataReqPgto = new System.DateTime();processo.vlrbruto = ; porém já tentei diversas formas e não consegui

Comment: use o método que vai funcionar

Comment: Sim amigo, tentei e vi que funciona, minha duvida é aplicar nessa linha do código     processo.numProcAnterior = "";
            processo.numProcJudicial = "";
            processo.numVara = 0;
            processo.vlrbruto =

Comment: Resolvido, fiz direto   processo.vlrbruto = Convert.ToDecimal(vlrbruto.ToString()); Valeu amigo

Comment: Se resolveu pode marcar como resposta  :)

Comment: Claro que sim, brother MarceloAWQ, muito obrigado ae pelas boas dicas, voc~e contribuiu muitíssimo ae para minhas dúvidas.